# Не работает в роутах метод post, ошибка MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, post, api, авторизация

При указании в роутах метода post - ошибка MethodNotAllowedHttpException?
Код роутов:

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        Route::get('news', 'NewsController@index');
        Route::get('news/{news}', 'NewsController@show');
        Route::post('news', 'NewsController@store');
        Route::put('news/{news}', 'NewsController@update');
        Route::delete('news/{news}', 'NewsController@delete');
    });

    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Не работают два последних. Что это может быть?

Comment: почему они отдельно от middleware?

Comment: Покажите код, который отправляет запросы.